# Log Trace levels logs to specific file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I have an .netcore app in which i use serilog for logging.
I am configuring logging in my program main method. I am logging Debug level logs to specific file and all other logs to another file. I want to also log trace level logs to spcefic file, But serilog does not have then enum in `LogEventLevel` Enum.  I tried used verbose but it didnt worked.

My Code:

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            //.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(
                outputTemplate: OutputTemplate)
            .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug).WriteTo.File(debugLogFilePath,
                outputTemplate: OutputTemplate,
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 100000000, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 3))
            .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug || e.Level == LogEventLevel.Verbose).WriteTo.File(logFilePath,
                outputTemplate: OutputTemplate,
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 100000000, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 3))
            .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Verbose).WriteTo.File(traceLogPath,
                outputTemplate: OutputTemplate,
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, fileSizeLimitBytes: 100000000, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 3))
            .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: _"**Verbose** - **tracing information** and debugging minutiae; generally only switched on in unusual situations"_ - [Writing Log Events](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#log-event-levels) , so your choice of "verbose" was just right. Let's focus on "it didnt worked". How so? Exceptions? No output? ...

Comment: No output. everything seems to be working fine

Comment: Do you get output into the other files? Are you _sure_ there was in fact "verbose" level log?

Comment: Sorry, it works. I had a bug at traceLogPath var. I will leave the question open for people who may need this code in the future

Comment: [_Serilog.Sinks.Map_](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map) is often a more elegant way to split events into multiple files; there's an example in the README over there.